# Can shader resource (texture) be on host while drawing?

Tags: memory-management, vulkan

I just wonder if we can bind the image (such as texture) that shader will use to a VkDeviceMemory that is allocated by flags HOST_VISIBLE | HOST_COHERENT.

Answer (score 2):

It can if your implementation allows it.

Before you can bind any `VkImage` to memory, you must first use `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements` to determine what memory types are allowed for that particular `VkImageFormat` and `VkImageType`. These are implementation defined properties. If the implementation says that a particular memory type can be used for that image, then you can use memory allocated from that memory type for that `VkImage` (and ones with similar parameters, as defined by the specification).

If it does not, then you cannot.

Comment: I agree it's implementation-dependent, but `vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties` doesn't have memory type as either an input or output. When you create the VkImage with the parameters you want, pass it to `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements`, and the `VkMemoryRequirements::memoryTypeBits` returned will indicate whether the image can be used in a `HOST_VISIBLE|HOST_COHERENT` memory type.

Comment: @JesseHall: Fixed.